# Mutually Exclusive MySQL Full-Text Search

Tags: php, mysql, match, space, full-text-search

Suppose I had a MySQL table with the following column:

```
   |variables|
1. | 'a'     |
2. | 'a b'   |
3. | 'a b c' |
4. |   ...   |
```

How can I construct a MySQL Full-Text search that doesn't ignore white space in the column entries?

For example, I would like the following query to return only row 1:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE MATCH variables AGAINST ('a')
```

As it is, however, this query would return rows 1–3 because all three rows contain the letter 'a'.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why you can't do a simple select * from table where variables = 'a' ?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm building a search query using a loop and for some columns I do want partial matches while for others I only want exact matches. I was hoping to keep my loop simple by only adding MATCH directives as opposed to switching between MATCH and a simple equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search rules are unclear, but this may be a case where a [regular expression search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) will serve you better than a full-text query.